# Visualizar xsl:value-of de una imagen XSL

Tags: xml, xsl

estoy aprendiendo xml, xsl y tengo dudas sobre como poder visualizar una imagen que yo dispongo en un elemento de mi archivo xml en el valor de xsl:value-of de un documento xsl, en mi documento xml para visualizar la imagen lo hice con una etiqueta html de esta manera

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sector.xsl"?>
<sectores>
<sector>
<nombre>Simon bolivar</nombre>
//lo hice de esta manera
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <img src="mercado.jpg" />                                                  
    </html>
</sector>
<sector>
<nombre>Quillan</nombre>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <img src="paisaje.jpg" />                                                  
    </html>
</sector>
</sectores>
```

y en el codigo de sector.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
<body>
    <h2>Sectores disponibles</h2>
    <tabl>
      <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Imagen</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="sectores/sector">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="nombre" /></td>  
        //Aqui es donde tengo la confusión sobre como poder visualizar la imagen, intente con utilizar el atributo image pero no resulto
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: al final tienes una transformcaion por parte de xsl simplemente agregas el tag de imagen y la referenca.

Comment: como amigo podrias darme un ejemplo?

Comment: ¿Por qué has puesto XHTML en tu documento XML? Normalmente el formato XML tiene su propio vocabulario, por ejemplo, podrías utilizar simplemente `<imagen>mercado.jpg</imagen>` y entonces en tu XSLT lo transformarías a HTML  `<td><img href="{imagen}"/></td>`.

Comment: amigo segui tus recomendaciones pero no me aparecen las imagenes